# Jitpack seems to be building the app.gradle instead of the myLibrary.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, jitpack

I have a library that I am trying to deploy to jitpack, but i keep getting I am trying to deploy a library on jitpack, but I keep getting build errors like these within the logs

```
Gradle 'publishToMavenLocal' task not found. Please add the 'maven-publish' or 'maven' plugin.
 See the documentation and examples: https://docs.jitpack.io

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/jitpack/build/app/build.gradle' line: 52
```

which ends up failing with the message

```
⚠️ ERROR: No build artifacts found
```

Looking at this line here `Build file '/home/jitpack/build/app/build.gradle' line: 52`, I assumed this is because jitpack was building my app module rather than my library module...

In order to fix this, I updated the jitpack.yml file to look like this

```
jdk:
  - openjdk11

project: library_folder_name
```

But that doesnt seem to fix the issue.

...

PS:

- When I publish to mavenLocal to test that publishing is setup correctly, that works without any issues.
- My artifact_id matches the repository name
- The group_id matches com.github.<MY_GIT_USER_NAME>